# Weblogic shared library multiple dependency version

Tags: java, web-applications, server, shared-libraries, weblogic

App server :Weblogic

I have 2 web applications .

- war1 depends on  jar, lets say x-1.0.jar(3rd party)
- war2 depends on jar, lets say x-1.1.jar(3rd party)

I want to put x-1.0.jar and x-1.1.jar in to a shared library and both the wars to point to the shared library.

How can i distinguish the versions of jar for the war using only 1 shared library?

Answer (score 0):

you can't ! You need a dedicated shared library per version of your jar. It is the purpose of shared libraries.